# Is there a way to undo recursive regex operations?

Tags: python, regex, string, recursion, substitution

If there's a regex operation that does recursive substitution, e.g.:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[?!]')
>>> s = 'what the?!'
>>> print(pattern.sub(r' \g<0> ', s))
what the ?  !
```

**Is there a way to undo the recursive operations?**

I've this but it didn't work:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[?!]')
>>> s2 = pattern.sub(r' \g<0> ', s)
>>> s2
'what the ?  ! '
>>> pattern2 = re.compile(r'\s[?!]\s')
>>> s3 = pattern2.sub(r'\g<0>', s2)
>>> s3
'what the ?  ! '
>>> pattern2 = re.compile(r' [?!] ')
>>> s3 = pattern2.sub(r'\g<0>', s2)
>>> s3
'what the ?  ! '
```

---

Comment: Regex101 explains it best =) https://regex101.com/r/WMP7zC/1

Comment: You compile `pattern2` and then sub with `pattern`?

Comment: In your regex101 link, you show that `\g<0>` recurses a subpattern in a search pattern, but you are using it in a replace pattern (where it is just a literal backreference). You also mix up PCRE and python patterns.

Comment: There is no recursion here, btw. In Python, `\g<N>` is an *unambiguous replacement backreference syntax*. It is not the PCRE/Oniguruma subroutine call syntax. You should reconsider the title. Actually, since there are no markers at the places where the initial replacement was made, there is no way to "undo" a regex replacement. However, the solution below should work in this case. Just use `r' ([?!]) '` pattern and replace with `'\1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your character class in parentheses to create a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Then during replacement, you can substitute the *whole* match (which includes the spaces) with just the *group* (which doesn't have the spaces).

```
>>> import re
>>> s2 = 'what the ?  ! '
>>> pattern2 = re.compile(r'\s([?!])\s')  # capture the punctuation part as group 1
>>> s3 = pattern2.sub(r'\g<1>', s2)       # replace the matches with the captured group 1
>>> s3
'what the?!'
```

Comment: Interesting! Could you also explain why is it that when doing the initial regex substitution, the group isn't used?

Comment: @alvas You're using group zero in your initial substitution. Group zero always refers to the *whole* match (imagine that your regex is implicitly surrounded by parentheses). In your initial substitution, the whole match is just the punctuation character; in your reverse attempts, the whole match also includes the surrounding spaces.

Comment: When referring to a group with ID more than 0, you do not even need the `\g<N>` notation, use `.sub(r'\1', s2)`. Also, if the `?` or `!` were enclosed with regular spaces, the pattern to "undo" that should also contain regular spaces, not the generic `\s` whitespace class.